# Does Microsft Publisher 2013 have connectors?

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-powerpoint, microsoft-office-2013, microsoft-publisher

Previous versions of MS Publisher, and other 2013 products like Powerpoint have connectors so that if you draw arrows between shapes and move the shapes around, the arrows move with it. This does not seem to work in Publisher 2013 even though circles representing connection points appear when I am drawing the line.

I find this extremely annoying considering that I made a drawing in Powerpoint, which I have to redraw in Publisher, since copying from Powerpoint and pasting it in Publisher results in an image (an not the editable shapes). And now Publisher won't let me connect lines.

Answer (score 0):

Under the shapes tab find lines, then select the elbow arrow connector.

That should work in the same way as the 2010 version.